# Looping wordpress Categories on Homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this code here on my wordpress homepage template however on my categories page I have another piece of code that loops the categories. I need help making this code loop, can you share with me the best way to do this.

```
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('product_category') ):
// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('product_category') ) : the_row();
$cat =  get_sub_field('category');  ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_category per_page = 4 orderby="rand" category="' . $cat->slug.'"]');?>
<?php endwhile;
endif;
```

trying to loop like this

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );
```

how do I loop,

```
echo do_shortcode('[product_category per_page = 4 orderby="rand" category="' . $cat->slug.'"]');?
```

any help would be great. on the category.php page I found the way it's looping like this,

```
php get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );
```

so i'm just trying to conbine the code with the upper `homepage.php`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list all the categories of post on your blog use  <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>. You can also pass $args inside this function. For more info read http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=25&showposts=3'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <li class="homeblock" style="max-width:400px;">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
        </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
            </li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The above code might help you get started.

All you need to change is `cat=25` to what ever the id of your category is.
And then change `showposts=3` to the amount of posts you would like to show.

The rest is just a matter of making a template for your loop.
If u use the above code without changing the template it would show a title, then the featured image, and finally the content of each post.

Comment: you can see an example of how we are using the code above here, http://www.911quotes.com/ what we want to do is just make it like the categories menu dropdown in the main nav which just uses. get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' ); it has a continuous loop as you scroll down the page.